# Monitor has yellow tint when used with the graphics card

Tags: display, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

I have an nVIDIA graphics card when used produces an yellow tint on my monitor's display. I tried with another monitor and it had the same issue. I then switched back to my motherboard's inbuilt graphics output (not sure what the technical term is), and the display seems fine, except I can't get the optimal resolution of 1440x900 to work.

So is my graphics card's life over? Or can I get it repaired? Any self remedies without calling a hardware guy?

Should I try with a DVI cable? I've been using the VGA cable from my graphics card to the monitor so far. Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First if you can, try to use different cable for monitor. It could be that cable is damaged. I've had seen problems such as yours on with damaged DVI->VGA adapters. If the cables are good, try with DVI->VGA adapter. It may help you if the VGA port on the card is damaged. If the monitors themselves have DVI ports, buy appropriate cable and do use them!

Also, check settings and make sure that they are OK. Try with some recent GNU/Linux LiveCD. If it works fine, try with driver reinstallation.

If all fails, post your graphics card's chipset and manufacturer. There might be a way to save it by baking it, if it's using certain chipset; but it's a drastic measure which should be applied to cards which would otherwise go to trash-can.

Oh and "motherboard's inbuilt graphics output" is usually called integrated video card.

**EDIT:**
You provided new information, so here's my response: clean your graphics card's cooling system! I've seen people talk on INTERNET that on older graphics cards, the solder ball grid array which connects the card's processor to circuit board can start to crack because the solder balls expand due to effects of heat. After the card cools down, they shrink. I believe that the best way to solve this is to wait until the card becomes unusable (you can prolong the time by providing better cooling) and then research card baking.
 If you manage to set correct temperature and properly heat up and later cool down the card, the solder balls may melt in a correct way and re-solder the processor correctly. There's some discussion of that on its dedicated question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/82853). Also take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_grid_array) for some m0re information.

On the other hand, it could be that the processor itself is cooked. Graphics cards of nVidia's 8000 series are especially susceptible to that problem because of low quality of raw materials used in manufacture. If it's this problem, then I'm afraid that there is no way to actually repair the card. One day it will fail and you'd have to obtain a new card.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! My monitor has a DVI port, I will try with a DVI cable first. Also, this yellow tint happens after I use the computer for 3 to 4 hours. The computer hangs with crazy colors on the monitor and I can only use it in safe mode. However, if I turn it off for 3 or 4 hours, the problem disappears for some time. So I guess it may not be the cable - I'm using the same cable for the integrated video card now.

But I will try this first and will get back with my results.